# Exact Renormalization Group

Tags: resource-recommendations, renormalization, effective-field-theory

I'm studying the Exact Renormalization Group in QFT.

I've found some pretty OK references already (see https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0002034 and https://arxiv.org/abs/1003.1366), but I was wondering if there is any other ones people recommend.

I'm looking for resources that aren't too detailed in a way that obscures the core message of ERG. In a sense I'm aiming at introductory texts but with some depth to the mathematics and such.

Comment: More on [exact renormalization group](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+%22exact+renormalization+group%22).

Comment: There are different flavors of eRG -- e.g., the Polchinski formalism vs the Wetterich, and it has been applied to a wide range of fields, from equilibrium and non-equilibrium classical statistical field theories to quantum systems including some quantum gravity models. Could you be more specific about which formalism(s) and areas you are interested in?

Comment: @bbrink the Polchinski formalism seems most interesting for my purposes, but I'd like to have a good general understanding as well.

Comment: I'm afraid I am much less familiar with the Polchinski formalism. Here are a few references I saved that may be helpful: https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/9308265 (Polchinski applied to phi4), https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9704094 (Polchinski vs Wetterich for O(N), https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0702365v1 (review of equilibrium methods, mostly focuses on Wetterich), https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.04853 (recent overview of many recent applications).