# Looking for examples of Polchinski's ERG

Tags: resource-recommendations, renormalization, effective-field-theory

This question is related to my older question on the [Exact Renormalization Group](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/765653/).

I've read through the first half the Rosten review (https://arxiv.org/abs/1003.1366) and the Bervillier paper (https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0002034) for a conceptual understanding, and for more specific calculations I went through https://arxiv.org/abs/0909.0327 and lectures I found on YouTube. At this point I have an OK understanding of what ERG actually is (coarse graining + rescaling and finding fixed points). However, these papers don't really deal with specific examples it seems and I want to get a better understanding of the ERG (specifically Polchinski's equation) through some examples. I'm sticking to only scalars at the moment, so something which deals with $\phi^4$ theory could be nice.

EDIT: I'm looking for resource recommendations of applications of Polchinski's ERG to get a better feel for the equations. For example, I was reading that with Polchinski's equation it was pretty easy to show perturbative renormalizability of the $\phi^4$ field theory in 4 dimensions. However, I haven't found a good source explaining this well. On the other hand I don't want to dive too deep in applications, as I have limited time to look into this.

Comment: Hi Geigercounter. This question (v1) seems to fit poorly to this SE Q&A site since it has non-unique answers.

Comment: @Qmechanic I've updated. Let me know if my question still needs to be edited for the physics SE standards.